# How do you select a particular item/component in React and then cycle through that array onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of returned items that are in the position of absolute. They are stacked on top of each other and I was wondering how to iterate through that with onClick method in react. I have two buttons that when you click one is supposed to go forward and one backwards, but I can't seem to get it. I want to target the house div but I can't seem to get the proper code to select that particular item. I have read the documents on event handling but none of it seems to work. Can someone point me in the right direction, as I am new to React?

Here is my code:

```
class Members extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userInput: null,
      senators: [],
      represenatives: [],
      bills: []
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
    })
  }

  right = (e) => {


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const key = `xCaHBd8gI5ZJSOUXWFJGOXZBjJtMbvoIcip0kSmS`
    const urls = [`https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/116/senate/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/102/house/members.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/statements/latest.json`,
      `https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/bills/search.json`];

    let requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url, {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'X-API-Key': key
      }
    }))
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then(res => {
        return Promise.all(res.map(res => res.json()));
      }).then(response => {
        this.setState({
          senators: response[0].results[0].members,
          represenatives: response[1].results[0].members,
          bills: response[2].results
        })
        console.log(this.state.senators)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }

  render() {

    const { senators, bills, represenatives, userInput } = this.state;

    const inSenate = senators.filter(
      (senator) => senator.state === userInput
    )

    const inHouse = represenatives.filter(
      (represenative) => represenative.state === userInput
    )

    const draft = bills.find(
      (bill) => bill.name === inSenate.last_name)



    return (

      <div className="congress">
        <div className="users">
          <h2>{this.state.userInput}</h2>
          <input className="userInput" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>

        {inSenate.map((senate, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={senate.id} className="senate">
              <h2 className="senateName">Senate</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <h2 >{senate.short_title + " " + senate.first_name + " " + senate.last_name}</h2>
                <li>{senate.title}</li>
                <li>State: <strong>{senate.state}</strong></li>
                <li>Party: <strong>{senate.party}</strong></li>
                <li>DOB: <strong>{senate.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li>Next Election: <strong>{senate.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li>Missed Votes: <strong>{senate.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li> Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li>Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{senate.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
        })}

        {inHouse.map((rep, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="house"> //this is what I want to cycle through
              <h2 className="numbers" >Your state has {inHouse.length} Represenative(s)</h2>
              <h2 >{rep.short_title + " " + rep.first_name + " " + rep.last_name}</h2>
              <ul className="bio">
                <li  >{rep.title}</li>
                <li  >State: <strong>{rep.state}</strong></li>
                <li  >Party: <strong>{rep.party}</strong></li>
                <li  >DOB: <strong>{rep.date_of_birth}</strong></li>
                <li  >Next Election: <strong>{rep.next_election}</strong></li>
                <li  >Missed Votes: <strong>{rep.missed_votes}</strong></li>
                <li  > Votes With Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_with_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
                <li  >Votes Against Party Percentage: <strong>{rep.votes_against_party_pct + "%"}</strong></li>
              </ul>
              <button className="left btn"></button>
              <button onClick={this.right} className="right btn"></button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have variable `i` here `{inHouse.map((rep, i) => {`.

`i` is your index in array `inHouse`. The `rep` is in fact `inHouse[i]`, so you can pass your index (`i`) to the onClick function as a parameter.

So this:

```
right = (e) => {}

...


<button onClick={this.right} className="right btn"></button>
```

Would be replaced with that:

```
right = (index) => {}

...

<button onClick={() => this.right(i)} className="right btn"></button>
```

Comment: Hi, could you expands on this, as I am having a hard time getting the logic to work?

Comment: @Alanaj in `right = (index) => {}` you have access to the index of the item you want to move, you can check it with console.log(index), so if right() is meant to move an item up in the array you can do inside body function, you have access to `this.state` there, so you can simply do `const inHouse = this.state.inHouse` do something with inHouse and set the state with that value.